# acedemic projects related to linux virtualization and security

Tags: security, virtual-machine, kvm

I am B.tech student iam totally confused with the topic virtualization. but i selected `linux virtualization security` as a project in my college. i tried in google but i found so many virtualization schemes. i selected KVM. where to start that KVM virtualization ? and **security regarding KVM virtualization**. to do the project in KVM virtualization do i need any special hardware. I need good books regarding this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should first do your homework, and clear up the separate topics "what is virtualisation" and "what is security and how can it be applied to/ is it implemented in different virtualisation methods" and "what specific use case do I choose for both together".

You should probably first create an overview for yourself
- what are virtualisation methods
- what is the difference between emulation and a hypervisor
- what should the scope be for project related to KVM

For starters, and an overview about virtulization methods, check e.g.
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Virtualization and 
http://virt.kernelnewbies.org/TechOverview

For KVM, read this part of the FAQ and also the rest there:
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#General_KVM_information

More generic overviews:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software

In general, KVM is only a hypervisor/set of driver modules. What you probably want to use, is either qemu directly or libvirt. Read up on this at e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM and http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ